# change root location to /system/xbin android

Tags: root-access, adb

i have a root android device, but su is located on / 
So, i wanna change my su to /system/xbin or /system/bin. but i can't change su while i'm using it.

I also need to change 2 files that are located in / and /sbin
However, every time I change them android returns the previous files after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem.

I got a workaround that changes the installation scripts not to save the su image to / data, but to / system, and by modifying the su startup script to mount su into / system as well. However this method only works by installing su via recovery (using TWRP_3.0.2).

I am still looking for an alternative to do within the system

I changed the scripts from SuperSU-v2.82 tool

https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu